# C++ thread exits after calling terminate called without an active exception

Tags: c++, multithreading, timer, thread-safety

I have created a timer class that is used for creating and deleting timers and I have a fixed number of timers that. Some timers are restarted after they have completed there callback function. In certain cases I might need to delete the timer. With this logic I came up with the following code:

The timer.cpp:

```
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>

class Timer
{
    public:
        Timer();

        ~Timer();

        void Start( const uint8_t pipeId, const uint32_t msPeriod);

        void Stop();

    private:

        void TimerCallbacktimer( const uint8_t pipeId);

        std::chrono::milliseconds msPeriod_;
        uint8_t pipeId_;
        std::thread thread_;
        std::condition_variable cv_;
        std::mutex mutex_;
        std::atomic<bool> stop_waiting_{false};
        std::atomic<bool> done_{false};


};


void Timer::TimerCallbacktimer( const uint8_t pipeId)
{
    //callback function left empty on purpose
}



void Timer::Start( const uint8_t pipeId, const uint32_t msPeriod)
{
    pipeId_ = pipeId;
    msPeriod_ = std::chrono::milliseconds(msPeriod);
    if (done_) //if the thread was already created and expired join it before restarting the thread
    {
        thread_.join();
        done_.store(false);
    }

    thread_ = std::thread
    {
        [this]() 
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mutex_);
            cv_.wait_for(lck, msPeriod_, [this]() { return stop_waiting_.load(); });
            if (not stop_waiting_)
            {
                TimerCallbacktimer(pipeId_);
                done_.store(true);
            }
        }
    };
}


void Timer::Stop()
{
    stop_waiting_.store(true);
    cv_.notify_one(); 
}



Timer::Timer()
{

}

Timer::~Timer()
{
    if (thread_.joinable())
    {
        thread_.join();
    }
}



std::vector<Timer> TimerArray(30);

std::mutex timerMutex;

void CreateTimer( const uint8_t slot , const int32_t pipeId, const uint32_t msPeriod )
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(timerMutex);
    TimerArray[slot].Start(pipeId, msPeriod);
}


void DeleteTimer( const uint8_t slot )
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(timerMutex);
    TimerArray[slot].Stop();

}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    
    CreateTimer(3, 3, 300);
    CreateTimer(4, 3, 100);


    DeleteTimer(4);

    CreateTimer(3, 3, 100);
    // sometimes I start the same timer immediately after it has called its callback function
    CreateTimer(3, 3, 100); 

    return 0;
}
```

As I do have a fixed number of timers, I do call the same timer again after I have
The problem that I am facing is that sometimes I get an error `terminate called without an active exception`. I can't seem to figure out why the error pops out. I thing that pops up in my head is basically that I am starting a timer again immediately after it has expired and I need to do some cleanup in the callback function to prepare it for it start again? Also should I join the thread whenever the callback function is completed?

Comment: Run your code under a debugger and it will tell you *why* terminate is being called.

Comment: now I can reproduce the crash. Note that for the sake of a mre, its simpler to place all code in a single file like I did here https://godbolt.org/z/a5T9Mn39o

Comment: As far as I can tell, you're not handling the case of trying to restart a thread that hasn't finished yet. Why do you only `join` on restart if the timeout has already passed?

Comment: @molbdnilo. I thought it would be more appropriate to join it at that point, I was thinking to call join in the callback but it gave additional errors when I did that

Comment: @newww I think the point isn't a problem, but the condition is. Why shouldn't you join a thread whose timeout hasn't expired yet before restarting?

Comment: @molbdnilo sorry am not understanding here, do you mean that after ever successful call of the callback  I should join the thread?

Comment: @newww No, I mean that you should `join` even if `done_` is false. The thread could still be running at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment by molbdnilo, you do not handle the case of calling `Start` when the timer is already running but not `done_` yet.

To restart the timer you can signal it to `stop_waiting_`, `join` it (and reset `done_` to its initial):

```
//if (done_) //if the thread was already created and expired join it before restarting the thread

// if the thread was already created, join it!
if (thread_.joinable()){
    stop_waiting_.store(true);
    thread_.join();
    done_.store(false);
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ooWKPrva5).

The crash in your code is caused by `thread_ = std::thread ...` before it has been joined. Its the same issue as with this very simplified code:

```
int main() {
    std::thread t{[](){
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
    }};
    t = std::thread([](){});   // -> terminates
}
```

For details I refer you to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/operator%3D) on `std::thread::operator=(thread&& other)`:

> If `*this` still has an associated running thread (i.e. `joinable() == true`), calls `std::terminate()`. Otherwise, assigns the state of `other` to `*this` and sets `other` to a default constructed state.
>
> After this call, `this->get_id()` is equal to the value of `other.get_id()` prior to the call, and `other` no longer represents a thread of execution.

Comment: the solution worked, but i had to change  stop_waiting_.store(true) to  stop_waiting_.store(false). As it brought up a deadlock

Comment: @newww hmm... the `stop_waiting_.store(true);` was too unblock the `wait_for` call that waits for `stop_waiting_` to be `true`. Otherwise `thread_.join();` has to wait for the timer to expire. Maybe I miss something, dont see the deadlock, but glad it helped.