# C++ timers synchronization with a timer class not executing when doing a stop before a start

Tags: c++, multithreading, timer

A few days back I asked the following question: [C++ thread exits after calling terminate called without an active exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77446229/c-thread-exits-after-calling-terminate-called-without-an-active-exception)

And got a response which got me working and now I was adding more functionality in my code and I came across a situation where sometimes my main code will end up calling a timer stop function before starting it. I want to handle this situation in my Timer class but I cannot figure it out.

In my code example below, I have deleted the timer[4] before creating it. Afterwards I end up creating it. When I do create it, the callback function is not executed? Why Is it not executing?

```
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>

class Timer
{
    public:
        Timer();

        ~Timer();

        void Start(const int32_t slot, const uint8_t pipeId, const uint32_t msPeriod);

        void Stop();

    private:

        void TimerCallbacktimer(const int32_t slot, const uint8_t pipeId);

        std::chrono::milliseconds msPeriod_;
        uint8_t pipeId_;
        int32_t slot_;
        std::thread thread_;
        std::condition_variable cv_;
        std::mutex mutex_;
        std::atomic<bool> stop_waiting_{false};
        std::atomic<bool> done_{false};


};


void Timer::TimerCallbacktimer(const int32_t slot, const uint8_t pipeId)
{
    std::cout<<"the timer callback for slot: "<<slot<<std::endl;
}



void Timer::Start(const int32_t slot, const uint8_t pipeId, const uint32_t msPeriod)
{
    pipeId_ = pipeId;
    slot_ =  slot;
    msPeriod_ = std::chrono::milliseconds(msPeriod);
    if (thread_.joinable())
      {
        stop_waiting_.store(false);
        thread_.join();
        done_.store(false);
        }

    thread_ = std::thread
    {
        [this]() 
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mutex_);
            cv_.wait_for(lck, msPeriod_, [this]() { return stop_waiting_.load(); });
            if (not stop_waiting_)
            {
                TimerCallbacktimer(slot_, pipeId_ );
                done_.store(true);
            }
        }
    };
}


void Timer::Stop()
{
    stop_waiting_.store(true);
    cv_.notify_one(); 
}



Timer::Timer()
{

}

Timer::~Timer()
{
    if (thread_.joinable())
    {
        thread_.join();
    }
}



std::vector<Timer> TimerArray(30);

std::mutex timerMutex;

void CreateTimer( const int32_t slot , const int32_t pipeId, const uint32_t msPeriod )
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(timerMutex);
    TimerArray[slot].Start(slot, pipeId, msPeriod);
}


void DeleteTimer( const int32_t slot )
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(timerMutex);
    TimerArray[slot].Stop();

}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
     // sometimes a delete timer may be called before actually starting the timer
    DeleteTimer(4);
    CreateTimer(3, 3, 80);
    CreateTimer(4, 3, 10);


    DeleteTimer(10);
     CreateTimer(10, 3, 300);

    CreateTimer(3, 3, 100);
    // sometimes I start the same timer immediately after it has called its callback function
    CreateTimer(3, 3, 100); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try using your debugger? Your debugger should easily show you the exact reason for this bug. This is exactly what a debugger is for.

Comment: According to my debugging by eyes: deleting a timer sets `Timer::stop_waiting_` to `true`. In `Timer::Start()`, you set `Timer::stop_waiting_` only if the `thread_` is joinable. In this case, it's not (no thread yet started). Hence `Timer::stop_waiting_` stays `true`. In the thread lambda, I see `if (not stop_waiting_)`...
Please, prove me right or wrong in your debugger... ;-)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat yes that is true, but when is set `stop_waiting_` to true the program just stops working